# Should I use thread safe Map?

Tags: java, dictionary, thread-safety

Suppose i have a map called 'A'

1. Thread 1 always replace the full map with another temp map. ( A= new map B)
2. One or more thread can get(no update) data from the map 'A' at the same time Thread 1 replacing the map 'A'

*Question :* Should i use thread safe map here?

Comment: If the new map is never changed after its publication (i.e. after Thread 1 executed `a = <your new map>;`, then a concurrent map does not provide any benefit. You should, however, set the reference referncing your map (i.e. `a` in my example) set to `volatile`.

Comment: Just a side note: what do you mean by "replace", do you mean "re-assign" the map using a new one? I think it's more preferable to clear the map and put new entries, but never "replace" it.

Comment: "re-assign" the map using a new one